How does iPhone voice control choose numbers to overlay in grid
I've recently had some accessibility testing carried out by a user using Voice Control on an iPhone. They were having a few issues selecting form fields (the form fields are definitely labelled correctly etc.) and so were using the numbers grid overlay to select things.
One of the users comments re: the Voice Control numbers grid was that there were a lot of numbers being shown on the page and sometimes the location of these was not as expected.
Does anyone know how the iPhone determines which elements on the page to assign numbers to and where to locate the numbers? I have looked around online but haven't managed to find any documentation for developers.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.
